# mingw32: key on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite3-ruby

When I try to boot up a rails server I get an error like `Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.` .

Later when I do `bundle install` or `gem install sqlite3`

```
error: mingw32: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" not recognized
error: cannot remotely look at key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04"
error: database 'mingw32' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

I get an error.

I would be glad if you could help on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows?

If you are, open your Gemfile.lock file and replace sqlite3 (1.4.2-x86-mingw32) with sqlite3 (1.4.2), then bundle install again

Comment: I was buying it on Windows, but I did different operations there, now it gives another error. I'm dealing with it. But on Linux it gives this error only as sqlite3 (1.4).